# How to pass parameters when redirecting to another method

Tags: spring, redirect, model-view-controller

In spring mvc if I want to redirect from one method to another method inside the same controller, how can I pass parameters for this method?

for example:

```
@GetMapping("/m1")
public ModelAndView m1(){
  //do some actions
  
  return new ModelAndView("redirect:/m2"); 
}

@GetMapping("/m2")
public void m2( Object param1, Object param2, HttpServletResponse response){

}
```

Plus, I tried a similar example where I need to pass an HttpServletResponse as a parameter to the second method using RedirectAttributes and I get an exception that says it can't be serialized. Is there any way to pass an HttpServletResponse as a parameter in a redirect without storing it in session?